# Regex: help to finish a regex in rubular

Tags: regex, rubular

I need a help to finish a Perl Regex to the context below:

```
[a-zA-Z:]

------------------------------------------
I have                      I need
------------------------------------------
> str(datasets::ris$)       datasets::ris
> plot(datasets::iris$      datasets::iris
str(datasets::iris$)        datasets::iris
plot(datasets::iris$        datasets::iris
str(iris$)                  iris
plot(iris$                  iris
plot(IRIs$                  IRIs
iris$                       iris
------------------------------------------
```

http://rubular.com/r/kyLAy679Ql

Thanks,

Comment: If you need a PCRE/Perl regex, why did you choose Oniguruma online tester?

Comment: Rubular is compatible with pcre I am using.

Comment: No, rubular supports Oniguruma. Regex101 supports PCRE.

Comment: Ok, if you need alpha chars and `:` before a `$`, you can really use [`[A-Z:]+(?=[$])`](https://regex101.com/r/hH0dG3/1)

Answer (score 1):

The results are at http://rubular.com/r/IgInzqrwwX

You just need to add a lookahead to your regex `[a-zA-Z:]+(?=\s*\$)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with an optional match and capturing group. Your desired text is available in captured group #1:

```
/(?:[^(\n]*\()?([a-zA-Z:]+)/
```

[Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/7R3nfoyPhU)

Comment: All match groups is OK: thanks.

But how can I get it? I'm under Delphi and using pcre.

<code>
  sTmp:= RegEx(string,
                           '(?:[^(\n]*\()?([a-zA-Z:]+)',
                           False);

  ShowMessage(sTmp);
</code>

Comment: Sorry I don't know Delphi but I am sure getting a captured group would be pretty straight forward as it is the most basic regex operation supported in all the regex flavors.